# Copy files from nested folders to new nested folders

Tags: r, copy, directory-structure

I am trying to copy a large number of files from one folder to another. We need to restructure the folders, so there is a translation from the old folder path to a new one. The old folder structure is also nested.

Currently the code I have is not throwing any errors, but is returning false on executing the file.copy for all files.

ETA: When I copy a single file, it works.

```
allFilePaths <- list.files('./oldTopLevelFolder', recursive = TRUE)

testIds <- c(1:4)
otherTestIds <- c(5:8)

allNewFolders <- paste('newTopLevelFolder', testIds, 'aFolderName', otherTestIds, sep = '/')

lapply(allNewFolders, dir.create, recursive = TRUE)

file.copy(from=allFilePaths, to=allNewFolders, 
          copy.mode = TRUE)
```

Comment: On further investigation, it seems that the 'to' parameter of file.copy has to be a single location. I'm going to try writing a function that will copy one file and then use apply to do it for multiple.  Will post solution if it works.

Answer (score 1):

file.copy can copy multiple files, but only to a single destination folder by the looks of it.

In order to copy a bunch of files into varying destination folders, the following will do the job, where `allOldFilePaths` is a column containing the old filepath where each file currently exists, and `allNewFilePaths` is a column containing the new folder path for each file.

```
# function to copy a single file
copySingleFile <- function(oldPath, newPath) {
  file.copy(from=oldPath, to=newPath, 
            copy.mode = TRUE)
}

# copy each file to its new folder path
mapply(copySingleFile, allFilePathsWithRoot, allNewFilePaths)
```